# Ruby undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I am working on a project and have encounter an error which I am not familiar with. When I run my code, I received 'undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)' which after some research means that target_floors[j] is nil. Why is this happening and how to I solve it?

```
def retrieve_floor(n, target_floors)

    smallestDifference = n
    toReturn = 0

    for i in 1..n
        tempDiff = 0
        for j in 0..target_floors.length
            difference = target_floors[j] - i
            if difference > 0
                tempDiff += difference
            else
                tempDiff += difference.abs
            end
        end
        if tempDiff < smallestDifference
            smallestDifference = tempDiff
            toReturn = i
        end
    end
    return toReturn
end
```

Comment: Since `target_floors` is being passed to this method, whoever is passing it provided the `nil` value in the array. How do you want to solve it? Is it expected that some elements of the array are `nil` or not? If not, then the caller is at fault. If they are, then you just need to check for `nil` (`if target_floors[j].nil? ...`).

Comment: It's more likely that `j` is greater than the last index of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Ranges of the form `first..last` include the endpoints, so you are iterating one beyond the end of the array.

You could instead use `0...target_floors.length` (which includes the 0 but excludes the end) but a better and more rubyish approach would be to use `each` to iterate over the array, rather than working with indices.